# Should I consider mean or sampled value for action selection in ppo algorithm?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, policy-gradients, proximal-policy-optimization

When considering the policy network in PPO algorithm, we need to fit a Gaussian distribution to the neural network output (for a continuous action space problem). When I use this network to obtain action, should I sample from the fitted distribution or directly consider the mean output from the policy network? Also, what should be the standard deviation of the fitted distribution?